# Проблема с виртуальной машиной и ssl

Tags: ubuntu, curl, ssl, https, kvm

Есть хост и гостевая машина. Проблема что в гостевой машине не правильно https сертификат определяется

например вывод команды `curl --verbose https://node2.king-host.ru:8080` для хоста

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://node2.king-host.ru:8080/
*   Trying 188.127.226.24...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to node2.king-host.ru (188.127.226.24) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=node2.king-host.ru
*  start date: May  6 23:00:53 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  4 23:00:53 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "node2.king-host.ru" matched cert's "node2.king-host.ru"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: node2.king-host.ru:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 07 May 2019 09:41:33 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
    "error": "Missing required X-Access-Token header."
* Connection #0 to host node2.king-host.ru left intact
```

А для гостевой следующее:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://node2.king-host.ru:8080/
*   Trying 188.127.226.24...
* Connected to node2.king-host.ru (188.127.226.24) port 8080 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
* SSL: certificate subject name (panel.king-host.ru) does not match target     host name 'node2.king-host.ru'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (panel.king-host.ru) does not match         target host name 'node2.king-host.ru'
```

Т.е. в гостевой ОС не тот сертификат получает (хотя адрес сервера к которому curl подключается тот-же и traceroute тоже идет к тому же серверу). Кто может подсказать в какую сторону смотреть, что бы понять в чем проблема

Comment: Похоже что в первом случае у curl есть конфиг. Попробуйте запустить с параметром -q (отменяет чтение конфига, должен идти первым). Вообще конфиг должен быть в ~/.curlrc

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, после добавления -q ничего не меняется. Да и врядли проблема с curl, т.к. проверял через `openssl s_client` и все та-же проблема, мне кажется что я упускаю что-то в настройках kvm. Эта проблема во всех машинах виртуальных, вторая под centos работает, поведение точно такое-же. А на хосте все впорядке

Comment: А update-ca-certificates не пробовали на гостевой делать?

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, пробовал, но похоже просто некорректные настройки iptables. Сейчас читаю и буду перенастраивать. Оказалось что проблема данная только для порта 8080 проявляется. А через 443 порт нормально все. И т.к. на машину проброшен тоже 8080 порт, то похоже она сама на себя уходила (а другие виртуалки на неё)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить самостоятельно. Может кому-то поможет.

Проблема была в неверно настроенных правилах nat. Все по порту 8080 попадало на виртуальную машину обратно.

Удалось выявить когда проверил работу через другой порт, в частности 80 и 443.